# How do I directly convert odd-r hex coordinates to axial coordinates?

Tags: c#, hex, coordinates, unity-game-engine

I'm making a hex-based game in Unity and want to simplify some code by switching coordinate systems. I haven't found a way to directly convert from odd-r to axial so... here I am.
If you don't know what I mean by odd-r and axial: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates.
I know I can convert to cube first and then to axial, but I'm wondering if there's any way to convert directly.